# How to encapsulate a obvious or related generic

Tags: c#, generics

**Context / My code**

Please take a look first at the following code snippets.

My First interface

```
public interface ISystemUser<T>
{
    T GetIdentifiedBy();
    ...omitted code...
}
```

My class

```
public class AccessObject<U,V,W> where U : ISystemUser<V>
{
    public U ContextUser { get; private set; }
    public IOType IOType { get; private set; }
    public List<W> RequestedObjects { get; private set; }

    ...omitted code...
}
```

**The Issue**

Now I have troubles with the following line

```
 public class AccessObject<U,V,T> where U : ISystemUser<V>
```

The issue is that I want in the generics of my **AccessObject** that I specified my type **U**, and **U** must be a class implementing the interface **ISystemUser**.

For me it feels totally unnecessary to specify the **V** in the AccessObject class definition. Because I want **U** to be an **ISystemUser** implementation, don't care about which generic was chosen in the **ISystemUser** definition because I don't use generic **V** at all further in my code of the **AccessObject**.

**The Question**

So basically, is there no way to get an easier to use result, for example like the following snippet ?

```
public class AccessObject<U,W> where U : ISystemUser
```

Because **U** would automatically indicate the type of **V**, no ?

Comment: *You* are not using any `ISystemUser<T>` member of type `V` in your code, but how about users of `AccessObject<U, V, W>` that access its `ContextUser` property and then call `GetIdentifiedBy`? For them, `V` needs to be set, which is why it needs to be nailed down for the access object.

Comment: As for your last remark: "Because U would automatically indicate the type of V, no ?" - no, it wouldn't. It is well possible to specify a type for `U` that implements `ISystemUser<T>` twice, for two different types `T`.